# Making two functions into one

Tags: c, function

I have two function which implement encoding and decoding respectively:

```
void
delta_encode (char *buffer, const unsigned int length)
{
 char delta = 0;
 char original;
 unsigned int i;
 for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
 {
  original = buffer[i];
  buffer[i] -= delta;
  delta = original;
 }
}

void
delta_decode (char *buffer, const unsigned int length)
{
 char delta = 0;
 unsigned int i;
 for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
 {
  buffer[i] += delta;
  delta = buffer[i];
 }
}
```

The thing I don't like about those is that they are quite alike, except for the += versus -= part. Is there a way to unite them into one function, which would ask the user whether he wants to encode or decode, and choose a -= or += version respectively. And if there is, what will the code for it look like? If there are several ways to do this, which is the best?

Comment: Personally, I would prefer them as individual functions.  It's clear from the name what each one does.  Don't be fooled into thinking that all code duplication is bad.  You need to draw the line between what is sensible and what is ridiculous.

Comment: Granted, but I treat this question as a code-writing and intellectual exercise, not as an exercise in what is clearly understandable to humans.

Comment: I don't say it's nonsense, why? I say that two functions are readily understandable, but one function I'm asking about probably wouldn't be.

Comment: Yeah okay, so as an intellectual exercise you're either going to duplicate code again or make it extremely inefficient.

Comment: "I don't say it's nonsense" -- You don't say that it's nonsense that C doesn't contain conditionals?

Comment: @JimBalter - yes, I decided not to point out the "hidden tag": "What..."

Comment: "If there are several ways to do this, which is the best?" -- Note that all three answers below are awful in some way ... which is not the fault of the answerers, it's because this is a bad thing to do in this case.

Comment: "I say that two functions are readily understandable, but one function I'm asking about probably wouldn't be. " -- Well, yes, exactly. And the one function is less efficient. So there's no reason to do this.

Comment: yes, all right, I didn't have efficiency on my mind at the moment.

Comment: @JimBalter - I agree the solutions are all awful; it's what comes from asking an awkward question like this... Sometimes that's what an "intellectual exercise" will do. Exploring a question will give insights, but they are not always what you expected to learn.

Comment: Then what the heck *did* you have in mind? Pointless complication, code unreadability, a maintenance nightmare, and a greatly increased chance of bugs? (e.g., Michael Liberman's solution is broken.)

Comment: @Floris Sometimes it just misleads. There are many examples where two pieces of code can be elegantly merged into one through some generalization, but you should have the generalization in hand before doing the merge ... just merging for merging's sake is unwise.

Comment: In that sense Anish's solution is the least objectionable - he keeps the original functions intact, just wraps them in an outer "shell of unity". But since decoding and encoding are fundamentally different operations, I'm not sure of the logical value of doing this. It's not like overloading a function - same functionality with different parameters deserves same function name; different functionality, not so much. Still we are learning from the exercise, I think.

Comment: Answering your questions: 1) Something in the language that might be suitable just for this kind of generalistion. 2) I only intended it to be read by me, I wouldn't show such complications to a normal person ;-) 3) same here: I will do the maintenance, in the blessed privacy of my own computer 4) and I will be annoyed by the bugs, be they as they may.

Comment: @JimBalter, Just curious, do you say the answers are awful because they all reduce efficiency?

Comment: @Floris Yes, tha was the goal: overloading allows to use the same functionality, which is a very neat idea and can be mor or less easily implemented in a language, but I was looking for an idea about functions with "reverse" functionality

Comment: I am surprised by the choice of "accepted answer". Can you explain your preference? Especially after your "this looks even closer" comment to another question...

Comment: @AnishRam No, I said they are all awful *in some way* ... for instance, yours just crams together two functions into one without any unifying of the sort the OP asked for. The others make the code considerably more complex. I just added my own answer, which I think is the cleanest, logically.

Comment: Oh, it was more of a mis-click than an actual choice. Sorry about that, my mouse's been doing that for months. Still, it's a good answer.

Comment: "Something in the language that might be suitable just for this kind of generalistion." -- In the language? What sort of thing could that be? "I only intended it to be read by me" -- You'll be a different person in 6 months and won't be able to read your own code. Do what competent professionals have learned to do ... always code as if it *will* be read by others.

Comment: "In the language? What sort of thing could that be? " -- I don't know, that's the point. I'm still learning C/C++, so how do I know if there is something like this? "You'll be a different person in 6 months and won't be able to read your own code. Do what competent professionals have learned to do ... always code as if it will be read by others"  -- yes, I'm learning that as well)

Comment: @JimBalter, The OP stated, _"...choose a -= or += version respectively". Doesn't my answer accomplish exactly that? It does unify the functions. It also seems much more readable.

Comment: @AnishRam The OP wrote "The thing I don'w like about those is that they are quite alike, except for the += versus -= part." -- the whole point is to combine/unify the logic -- see the OP's comment/complaint on my answer. You didn't combine anything other than the similar function prototypes.

Comment: @JimBalter, Yeap. You're right. Also, your answer definitely seems cleaner :)

Comment: " I'm still learning C/C++" -- You tagged this C; C++ is a quite different language. Notably, C is very primitive and has very little syntactic sugar or other sorts of magic to help out here. All the answers are based on straightforward logic, not language features.

Comment: Yes, I did, since the original code is in C. But if there is  a C++ concept for reversing functionality as mentioned before, I'd very much like to learn it.

Comment: I thought about it some more and C *almost* has a language feature that would do this for you ... see the edit to my answer. All it would take is a generalization of postfix -- to subtract *any* value, not just 1.

Comment: ...  So actually your question is a lot more valid than I realized ... ironically, I was blinkered by my knowledge of C.

Comment: @Floris "Exploring a question will give insights, but they are not always what you expected to learn." -- You are very much right. I apologize for being so hardnosed.

Comment: @jimbalter - no worries. Engaging passionately in a debate is something I really appreciate, and that's what you did. "Listening", by my favorite definition, is hearing what others have to say, AND being prepared _to be changed by what you hear_. Apology accepted with one reservation only: it wasn't needed.

Comment: Oh. I wasn't actually in a debate, I was learning. And appear to have learned a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the same code but for a sign, you could add a `encode/decode` parameter to your function call, and multiply the thing you are adding by `-1` if you have the encode version. Thus:

```
typedef enum {ENCODE = -1; DECODE = 1;} CODE_TYPE;

void delta_code(char *buffer, const unsigned int length, CODE_TYPE e);

void delta_code(char *buffer, const unsigned int length, CODE_TYPE e) 
  {
  char delta = 0;
  char original;
  unsigned int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
    original = buffer[i];
    buffer[i] += delta*e;
    delta = (e<0)?original:buffer[i];
    }
  }
```

Comment: wow) didn't think about, but this looks even closer to what I envisioned as an answer: short, unifying and apparently complicated

Answer (score 2):

As long as this is an "intellectual exercise", I might as well post this, which captures the symmetry of encode/decode:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void delta_code(char *buffer, const unsigned int length, bool encode) 
{
    char delta = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        char next_delta;
        if (encode)
        {
            next_delta = buffer[i];
            buffer[i] -= delta;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[i] += delta;
            next_delta = buffer[i];
        }
        delta = next_delta;
    }
}
```

Edit: The OP referred to language features. If C had a generalized postfix subtract, say `=-` that worked like postfix `--` in that it returned the value of the left side *before* the subtraction, then you could do this:

```
   for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
       delta = encode? (buffer[i] =- delta) : (buffer[i] += delta);
```

Of course, in real C you could do

```
      char temp;
      for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
          delta = encode? (temp = buffer[i], buffer[i] -= delta, temp) : (buffer[i] += delta);
```

Comment: I like the visual symmetry too, but I hoped to deal with the whole +\- thing.

Comment: It can't both be symmetric and fold +/- together because encode and decode have *two* differences, one being + vs. - and the other being whether the delta is the old value or the new value. And the point of this isn't the visual symmetry (although that falls out nicely), but the *logical* symmetry ... you can see precisely how encode and decode differ.

Comment: Yes, and as a "delta-oriented" solution it is quite good, I think.

Comment: Now, after all this discussion I realise that the last part of that question is probably the very thing I expected to see as an answer. So thanks for that.

Comment: I'm curious what the downvote is about, but I doubt I'll ever find out.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everyone who said doing this is bad. It makes your program less efficient and your code clunkier (thereby reducing readability). If you ever encounter such a roadblock while implementing a design, you might want to re-think your design and *why* such a requirement even exists.

All that being said, you could do something like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    ENCODE,
    DECODE
} CONTEXT;

void
delta_operation (char *buffer, const unsigned int length, CONTEXT context)
{
    if(context == ENCODE)
    {
        char delta = 0;
        char original;
        unsigned int i;
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            original = buffer[i];
            buffer[i] -= delta;
            delta = original;
        }
    }
    else if(context == DECODE)
    {
        char delta = 0;
        unsigned int i;
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] += delta;
            delta = buffer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
char buffer[] = "Whatever your buffer is supposed to be";
delta_operation (buffer, strlen(buffer), ENCODE);
```

Comment: Well, I explained the why earlier, and, simply put, it might be "to see if I can". But I see the more general considerations, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I agree with @paddy. You should not make your code unreadable just to get less code lines.

In general if you want to switch between += and -= you can use (+/-1) multiplier. For += you should use multiplier = 1 and then you will get:

```
buffer[i] = buffer[i] + multiplier * delta ==> buffer[i] = buffer[i] + delta
```

and for the -= you can use multiplier = -1 and then you will get:

```
buffer[i] = buffer[i] + multiplier * delta ==> buffer[i] = buffer[i] - delta
```

Specifically for you code it could look something like that (you can use boolean instead of int and asign the value in the function):

```
void
delta_encode_decode (char *buffer, const unsigned int length, int shouldDecode)
{
 char delta = 0;
 char original;
 unsigned int i;
 for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
 {
  original = buffer[i];
  buffer[i] = buffer[i] + shouldDecode * delta;

  if (shouldDecode == 1)
    delta = buffer[i];
  else
    delta = original;

 }
}
```

OR more "elegant" solution (contribution of Anish Ram):

```
typedef enum
{
    ENCODE = -1,
    DECODE = 1
} eOperation;
```

and use the eOperation instead of the hardcoded values of -1/+1 and the int parameter

Comment: Well, this perhaps is what I wanted: still quite clear, but shorter.

Comment: @Chiffa, Well suppose you need another function in the future, whose functionality differs from that of encode/decode by some other lines, then your maintainability will decrease if using this method. This is why, in my answer, I used an `enum` and then your generic function does different stuff based on the argument.

Comment: Yes, I agree that your solution is more general in this sense, but for just two functions the question is about I like the "multiplier solution" more.

Comment: My solution - without having seen the other two as I was writing it - seems to combine the best of both worlds - I use an `enum` for clarity, but use values of `-1`, `+1` to use them directly as a multiplier... I do think the code as written here has a problem - it seems `shouldDecode` must be either `-1` or `+1`, and the test `if(shouldDecode)` will be true in either case.

Comment: Glad to see the test changed to `if (shouldDecode == 1)`... you're welcome.

Comment: Besides the problem of combining these specific functions and making them unreadable I gave the multiplier answer as an example of combining -= and += which I saw was the core issue here. To make my code more "elegant" (and again in this case I would not combine those two functions) you can add an ENUM with values -/+1 but still keep it short with the multiplier. Added to my original answer.

Comment: Thanks Floris ;). This is what happens when you write the code with one hand and hold coffee with the other.

Comment: Starting to look a lot like my answer now... :-) my code had the +1, -1 version. Anish just had a regular enum (starting at 0, not used directly as multiplier).

Comment: :) saw yours just now Floris.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something nobody else seems to have suggested yet.  You can make a kernel function to do the operation on a single character and pass it in.

```
typedef void (*delta_op)( char *value, char *delta );

void encode( char *value, char *delta )
{
    char prev = *value;
    *value += *delta;
    *delta = prev;
}

void decode( char *value, char *delta )
{
    *value -= *delta;
    *delta = *value;
}
```

Then you just pass your kernel function to the main part.

```
void encode_decode( char *buffer, unsigned int length, encode_op operation )
{
    char delta = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        operation( &buffer[i], &delta );
    }
}
```

So you call like this:

```
encode_decode( buffer, length, encode );
encode_decode( buffer, length, decode );
```

It'll be clunky and slow though....  like `qsort`.  Because of all the function calls.

Comment: But it doesn't combine the +/- logic, which is what the OP was looking for. Floris's answer manages that, with some pain ... but see the bottom of my answer, which manages it in a fantasy version of C.

Comment: On second thought, I don't combine +/- ... only Floris manages that.